# How to access value of queryset's all value_list values in HTML?

Tags: python, html, django, list, tuples

I am working on django currently. I have many-many relationship in models. Suppose one user can have several computer systems, IP, ports, etc. I am able to get all such values by providing the username.

**Problem**:

I am getting a queryset like this:

> <QuerySet [(1, '828234y8y', 'hn', 'hbhb', 'bhjh', 'hbj'), (2,
> '9299338uu8u', 'hbhb', 'hbhb', 'bhb', 'bhbh')]>

after I use this command:

```
selected_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
all_mac = selected_user.userl.all().values_list()
```

The main problem is that i want to pass these values to HTML as context so that for each value in queryset I have a row. Example, a row with ('828234y8y', 'hn', 'hbhb', 'bhjh', 'hbj'), then a row with ('9299338uu8u', 'hbhb', 'hbhb', 'bhb', 'bhbh') and so on.

**What I have tried**:

I tried to put queryset result in a list. So it became a list of tuples.

```
all_mac = list(all_mac)
```

But, if I pass this list of tuples to HTML like:

```
return render(request, "users/showMachines.html", {'machines': all_mac})
```

I use it in HTML like:

```
{% for user in machines %} {% for mac in user %}
<tr> <td>{{ mac }}</td><tr>
```

I see empty rows in my table. I also tried accessing like mac.0 using index in hope that it shows something but no luck.

**Help needed**:

Any help is appreciated that helps me get the row values visible as I want. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want a row for each tuple and a cell for each value in the tuple, so your template should more look like the following:

```
 {% for user in machines %} 
        <tr> 
        {% for mac in user %}
               <td>{{ mac }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```